# Pytest parametrized django_db mark required

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am writing unit tests for a function. In parameterize, I am generating tests cases by making some DB calls when required.

```py
def my_function(tokens):
    pass

def generate_tokens_helper(**filters):
    tokens = list(MyTable.objects.values(**filters))
    return tokens

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestMyClass:

    @pytest.mark.parameterize(
        "tokens, expected_result",
        [
            (
                generate_tokens_helper(),
                True
            )
        ],
    )
    def test_my_function(self, tokens, expected_result):
        assert expected_result == my_function(tokens)
```

This is generating the following error:

```
test_file.py:47: in <module>
    class TestMyClass:
test_file.py:17: in TestMyClass
    generate_token_helper(),
test_file.py:5: in generate_token_helper
    items = list(MyTable.objects.values())
spm/accessors/variable_accessor.py:182: in get_all_operators
    operator_list = list(qs)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:269: in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1308: in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:53: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1154: in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py:26: in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:259: in cursor
    return self._cursor()
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:235: in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
E   RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

I have already marked `TestMyClass` with `django_db` but I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following:

- I have written a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) function `generate_tests_for_my_function`
  which will make the necessary DB calls to generate the unit test inputs.
- Then, I have used this fixture for [indirect parameterization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) in the `test_my_function`.

So, the fixture is first evaluated which generates the test inputs. Then these test inputs are passed to the test function.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def generate_tests_for_my_function(request):
    """Returns a tuple of (tokens, expected_result) as per the test_id"""
    test_id = request.param
    if test_id == 0:
        filters = [] # some filters
        return (generate_tokens_helper(**filters), True)
    elif test_id == 1:
        filters = [] # some filters
        return (generate_tokens_helper(**filters), True)


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestMyClass:
    @pytest.mark.parameterize("generate_tests_for_my_function", [0, 1], indirect=True)
    def test_my_function(self, generate_tests_for_my_function):
        tokens, expected_result = generate_tests_for_my_function
        assert expected_result == my_function(tokens)
```

***This is still a bit tedious as I have to add a new test id and a new `if` condition if I want to add new tests. Please comment if this can be further improved.***

Comment: Perhaps you can use a list for the `test_id`s that returns the tuple: `if test_id in [0, 1, 2, 3]` as opposed to adding multiple `elif`s when you add new test values.

Comment: @ChristopherTabula, there are certain `filters` that I have to pass for each test case. I have updated the question & answer.

Comment: Then you should create a dictionary of filters with the test ids as keys: `filters = { 0: [ # some filters ], 1: [ # some filters ] }` so that in your condition you can do this `if test_id in list(filters.keys())` and within the `if` block you can access the filters this way: `generate_tokens_helper(**filters[test_id])`. Maybe not the most ideal solution but this will simplify your fixture.